# sqoop hadoop-mapreduce does not exist

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

**I run a import command on sqoop and I face the below issue. Can someone help me with this.**

Error: /usr/local/sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/bin/../../hadoop-mapreduce does not exist!
Please set $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME to the root of your Hadoop MapReduce installation.

**My bashrc:**

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/libexec
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_PID_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/pids
export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/logs
export HADOOP_HOME_WARN_SUPPRESS=true
export HADOOP_PREFIX=$HADOOP_HOME
export PATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:/usr/local/sqoop/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Sqoop installation in `PATH` and `error` does not match.

> export PATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:**/usr/local/sqoop/bin**:$PATH
>
> Error: **/usr/local/sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/bin/../../hadoop-mapreduce** does not exist! Please set $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME to the root of your Hadoop MapReduce installation.

**1.** Your `PATH` says sqoop is located at `/usr/local/sqoop` but your error points sqoop location to `/usr/local/sqoop-1.4.5...`. Give the correct location for sqoop and hadoop home.

**2.** Export `HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME` in `sqoop.sh` (found in `$SQOOP_HOME/bin`). Now execute, `sqoop import` command.

Comment: I have created a soft link for the sqoop installation at /usr/local/sqoop. Sqoop home and Hadoop home are as mentioned above and it is working fine. I am able to run list tables command using sqoop. But import query is failing with the error mentioned.

Comment: Does this path `/usr/local/sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/bin/../../hadoop-mapreduce` exists? Could you post your sqoop import command?

Comment: By default sqoop looks at the location /usr/local/sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/bin/../../hadoop-mapreduce as per the documetation. But if the HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is set properly it should override the default search location.

Comment: sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://stagedb/patientimport?zeroDateTimeBehavior=round --username appsUser --password XXX --escaped-by \\ --fields-terminated-by '\t' --query "SELECT * FROM patientimport where \$CONDITIONS limit 100" --num-mappers 1 --direct --target-dir /user/paas/patientimport

Comment: Try to export `HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME` in `sqoop.sh`. Also, does `sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://stagedb/patientimport...` command works for you? Most cases the command looks like, `sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname --username...`.

Comment: The above option didnt help.

Comment: What does `echo $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME` results? The `/usr/local/sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/bin/..` shows hadoop version as 2.0.4 and `export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/libexec` shows hadoop version as 2.6.0. Do you have two hadoop versions installed?